# Simple calculator needs a minimum output number

Tags: math, calculator

I have built a simple calculator [here](https://safety-backbone.webflow.io/pricing). The input can be any number, but the output needs to be a minimum of **500** when the input is less than 100. I am not an expert here, so this is about as far as I've got on my own. Would appreciate any help!

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="drivercount" value="100">
<input type="number" name="pricing" value="500">
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    var drivers = parseFloat($(':input[name="drivercount"]').val(),10);
    var v = '';
    if (!isNaN(drivers)){
      v = (drivers * 5);}
  $(':input[name="pricing"]').val(v.toString());
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a stackblitz snippet for the part of code that doesn't work properly. of your code. I'm afraid the link to your website can be seen as a form of advertising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple ternary on your multiplication before you set the variable to check if the value is less than or equal to 100.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    var drivers = parseFloat($(':input[name="drivercount"]').val(),10);
    var v = '';
    if (!isNaN(drivers)){
      v = (drivers <= 100 ? 500 : drivers * 5);}
  $(':input[name="pricing"]').val(v.toString());
  });
});
```